# How would I go about swapping different transparent images with others in visual basic 6?

Tags: image, vb6

So I have a programming project that I have to do for my school. What I have to do is setup a 2 player dice game. I could have gone the easy way and just display the number of the 2 die, but I was thinking of using images that I made in photoshop instead. However, the problem is that I do not know how to change images in an efficient way.

My first option is using the visibility tag on several images laid on top of eachother and change it accordingly as such

```vb
image1.visible = false
image2.visible = true
```

However, I do not think that is very efficient. Images also do not support changing the image with code from my research.

Secondly, I could use a PictureBox instead, which do support changing the image as the program is running. However, it does not support transparency, and the die images are transparent. Plus it gives me the invalid image file error, I guess due to the transparency in the gif files.

There is also the cheap workaround of me making the background of the images the same as the form background.

So is there a more efficient way I am missing out? I know that the cheap workaround would be the best option for this case, but I would like to have this knowledge for future use like semi-transparent pixels that blend in and such.

And before you ask, no, I cannot use another programming language as visual basic 6 is what my school teaches. Thankfully they are changing it soon, but I am stuck with this for now.

Comment: Why on earth are you getting school projects in VB6?

Comment: @Slugsie I get the impression that is common in some places, but I don't know why either.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out you CAN change the pictures of Images, while keeping transparency and stretch. I am going to properly show it:

```vb
Image1.Picture = LoadPicture("YOURPATHHERE.gif")
```

This is what I get for believing what I've seen on some forum.

Also, the error of invalid image file was due to the images being corrupted for some reason.

Comment: So "never mind?"